# The simplest way of defining 2_dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need an 2_dimensional array in c++ which gets the dimension from user. How can I define an int 2_dimensional array in c++? I found something that define a 1_dimensional array then define other array in each element. like this:

```
int **ary = new int[sizeY];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++)
    ary[i] = new int[sizeX];
```

Is there any other simple way?

Comment: How about using a vector so it manages the memory for you. That way you don't have to worry about deleting it yourself. Something like `std::vector<std::vector<int>> ary(sizeY, std::vector<int>(sizeX));` should do it for you.

Comment: Looks fine. And there isn't an easier way (unless there are smallish limits on the dimensions, in which case you could just declare a two-dimensional array of maximal dimension. It isn't that we have to make all fit into 64KiB anymore...)

Comment: The simplest would be to write a 2D array class, possibly using an `std::vector` for data storage. Make it manage its own resources, have reasonable copy and assignment, and you don't have to worry about this problem ever again.

Comment: Actually, the *simplest* (but also the least recommended) way would be `type array[N][M];`. There are many other ways, most of them better in various ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a vector of a vector to do a 2 dimension array in c++

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > myarray;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++)
{
     myarray.push_back(std::vector<int>());
     for(int j = 0; j < sizeX; j++)
     {
          myarray[i].push_back(0);
     }
}
```

And you can access your element with  myarray[y][x]

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myarray(sizeY, std::vector<int>(sizeX));
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the simpliest method is to use [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). With it you can write code like this:

```
vector< vector<int> > arr(rows, vector<int>(cols, 0));
```

This will create a new 2d vector which you can use like array. As far as I am conserned this method is more preferable because you don't have to think about releasing memory.